# How to attach a memo note to a transaction with Phanton or cli wallet?

Tags: send-transaction, memo

I see that I can attach a memo note when I use Trust wallet to send solana. But I don't see this option when using Phantom? How does one attach a note using Phantom or the CLI wallet?

What is the max length of this attached memo message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phantom doesn't currently have that option.

With the CLI you can use the `--with-memo <MEMO>` flag.

```
solana transfer --with-memo <MEMO> <RECIPIENT_ADDRESS> <AMOUNT>
```