# How do I add a note / memo to my Solana transactions using web3.js?

Tags: send-transaction, memo

Some Wallet apps allow Notes (sometimes also called 'memos') attached to transactions. This other question also mentions [notes can be made with the CLI](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/how-to-attach-a-memo-note-to-a-transaction-with-phanton-or-cli-wallet):

Here's a transaction with a note I made earlier:

[image]

I can see [transaction ID PdX96DWpeMRqjxP7tQHU7aVMkjongnQz7mmkLPmvtezvWoJzqnVfJpYu3xxmRWSTngKDQ9A7a4UP4s4Tj463jr4](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/PdX96DWpeMRqjxP7tQHU7aVMkjongnQz7mmkLPmvtezvWoJzqnVfJpYu3xxmRWSTngKDQ9A7a4UP4s4Tj463jr4/inspect) has an additional instruction to the `note...` program (`noteD9tEFTDH1Jn9B1HbpoC7Zu8L9QXRo7FjZj3PT93`) specifically, which when decoded from Hex to UTF-8

```
const note = hexToUtf8(`54657374206e6f746520746f20726563697069656e742066726f6d204d696b65`);
expect(note).toEqual("Test note to recipient from Mike");
```

**How do I add a note to my Solana transactions using web3.js?** Is there documentation for the note program somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question to help others - there seems to be two common ways to add comments to transactions:

- A `note` program at `noteD9tEFTDH1Jn9B1HbpoC7Zu8L9QXRo7FjZj3PT93` used by Glow Wallet. **I do not know who runs this program and where it is documented.**
- The `memo` program `MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr` which is a popular SPL app, [`memo` is documented in the SPL docs](https://spl.solana.com/memo) and [`memo` is also documented in the Solana cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-add-a-memo-to-a-transaction). [Quicknote also has memo docs](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/how-to-use-the-solana-memo-program)

```
const transferTransaction = new Transaction().add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: fromKeypair.publicKey,
    toPubkey: toKeypair.publicKey,
    lamports: lamportsToSend,
  })
);

transferTransaction.add(
  new TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [{ pubkey: fromKeypair.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true }],
    data: Buffer.from("Data to send in transaction", "utf-8"),
    programId: new PublicKey("MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr"),
  })
);

await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transferTransaction, [fromKeypair]);
```