# Is payment description(comment) available on Solana?

Tags: transactions, solana-pay

I want to create an app where users can make transactions and be able to leave a comment or description about that transaction. Is there a functionality to store that value on chain in Solana?

Comment: Solana Memo program https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/how-do-i-add-a-note-memo-to-my-solana-transactions-using-web3-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a note / memo to my Solana transactions using web3.js?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/how-do-i-add-a-note-memo-to-my-solana-transactions-using-web3-js)

Comment: Thanks, but no. I am not using JS in my app therefore I was looking for a general solution web3.js is not what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memo program is probably what you want: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/getting-started/how-to-use-the-solana-memo-program

Comment: Can other people see that memo for example on Solscan?

Comment: Yeah there is an instruction and you can see the memo in the program log. See the docs https://spl.solana.com/memo

Answer (score 3):

This feature will be added in Token 2022, you will be able to configure an asset where a memo is needed on transfer:

https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#required-memo-on-transfer

Currently you can write the memo functionality into your program, but you cannot stop people from sending transactions without a memo if their wallet is the owner of the account.

Usually developers will work around this by making all the tokens owned by the program (through PDA accounts) and building all transfer logic within the program.